# Graphviz: how to reduce the top and bottom margins of a node?

Tags: graphviz

[image]

How can I reduce the top and bottom margins of these Graphviz nodes? I am specifying "0.05, 0.0 as the margins to each node, with fontsize = 8.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
digraph { rankdir = LR
    node [shape=box margin=0 width=0 height=0]
    asdf [label="asdf\nasdf"]
    qwer [label="qwerqwer"]
    asdf -> qwer
}
```

Comment: specify margin for x and y `margin="0.1,0.5"` see https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:margin

Comment: @Alex see comment above

Comment: Strangely, this didn't work for me (setting `"0,0"`).

Answer (score 4):

Nodes have a default minimum size (width and height), so if you reduce margins beyond a certain point, it has no effect. At least, this is how it works with box (rectangular) nodes and some of the other simple shapes.

`width` and `height` actually specify the *minimum* width and height, not the actual width and height (unless you also specify that sizes are fixed). So to get smaller margins, you can just use very small `width` and `height` values, and the shapes will still be stretched to fit the labels.

With defaults:

```
digraph {
    node [shape=box]
    a -> "longer name"
    "longer name" -> "taller\nname"
}
```

[image]

Smaller:

```
digraph {
    node [shape=box,width=0.1,height=0.1]
    a -> "longer name"
    "longer name" -> "taller\nname"
}
```

[image]

You can also set the margin itself if you want it smaller:

```
digraph {
    node [shape=box,width=0.1,height=0.1,margin=0.01]
    a -> "longer name"
    "longer name" -> "taller\nname"
}
```

[image]